# How does the default SSL verification in Chef 12 work on windows nodes?

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Running on prem chef

According to the docs: "Chef server 12 enables SSL verification by default for all requests made to the server, such as those made by knife and the chef-client"

If I bootstrap a new node (just adding the chef-client default recipe to the run list) it looks like it sets up SSL verification and if I run chef-client on that node manually after its bootstrapped I see no SSL verification warnings. I see the self-signed cert for the Chef Server in `c:/chef/trusted_certs`

But that self-signed cert is not added to the computers trusted root store. How is it "verified"? Does chef use its own mechanism to verify the self-signed cert, I thought it would have to be installed in the computers local cert store for it to be trusted by Chef but apparantly not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef, or rather Ruby, uses OpenSSL which can't use the Windows cert store at all. Specifically we ship a copy of the curl cacert bundle file that is the base store and then everything in trusted_certs gets added to the TLS content in our `Chef::HTTP` code.

Comment: Worth mentioning `knife bootstrap` copy the workstation `trusted_cert` directory to the node, explaining why the cert is present even on first run.